# Renderizando Partials em ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Estou tendo um problema em minha aplicação onde eu queria usar partial pra renderizar uma página dentro de outra. Ou seja, um controller dentro de outro. Só que, o que acontece é o partial não renderiza de forma alguma e eu já fiz de quase tudo, mas ele não aparece.

Aqui a parte onde fica o código que chama o partial:

```
  <div id="ocorrencias" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
            @if (Model.Ocorrencias.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var ocorrencia in Model.Ocorrencias)
                {
                    @Html.Partial("_AdicionaOcorrencia", ocorrencia)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                <div>Ainda não há ocorrências</div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

Diretórios e seus respectivos arquivos:

## Alunos:

- _AdicionaOcorrencia.cshtml
- Adiciona.cshtml
- Detalhes.cshtml
- Edita.cshtml
- Index.cshtml
- Remove.cshtml

## Ocorrencias:

- Adiciona.cshtml
- Detalhes.cshtml
- Edita.cshtml
- Index.cshtml
- Remove.cshtml

## Shared:

Dentro de Shared tenho o diretório EditorTemplates e nele contém:

- Collection.cshtml

Dentro de Shared:

- _Layout.cshtml
- _LoginPartial.cshtml
- Error.cshtml

## Controller

```
    private EntidadesContext db; //= new EntidadesContext();

    public OcorrenciasController(EntidadesContext contexto)
    {
        this.db = contexto;
    }
     public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var ocorrencias = db.Ocorrencias.Include(o => o.Aluno);
        return View(ocorrencias.ToList());
    }

    public ActionResult Adiciona(long id) /* Esse Id é de Aluno, não de Ocorrencia */
    {
        var aluno = db.Alunos.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
        var ocorrencia = new Ocorrencia
        {
            Aluno = aluno
        };
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View(ocorrencia);
    }
     public ActionResult Edita(Ocorrencia ocorrencia)
    {
        db.Entry(ocorrencia).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View(ocorrencia);
    }
     public ActionResult Remove(long? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Ocorrencia ocorrencia = db.Ocorrencias.Find(id);
        if (ocorrencia  == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View(ocorrencia);
    }
```

Comment: Tenta `@Html.Partial("/Alunos/_AdicionaOcorrencia", ocorrencia)`

Comment: E qual é o erro que dá?

Comment: Já fiz dessa forma. E se eu coloco dessa forma ai, ele dá erro falando que não encontra o arquivo. Já coloquei a partial até na pasta Shared e ele não acha de jeito nenhum. E simplesmente não dá erro nenhum, só não aparece a partial.  Só o texto que lá na div dentro do else.

Comment: Então, num tem nada mesmo, porque eu não populei a parte de ocorrências pelo fato de não conseguir renderizar o partial pra testar e cadastrar alguma coisa. É estranho, pois deveria estar renderizando, pois esse partial é pra cadastrar e não pra listar... O de listar nem fiz ainda, porque to tentando entender o porque de num estar aparecendo nada.

Comment: Já não estou a entender nada. Não estás a passar itens no model, então como queres que ele não va para o else?

Comment: O que acontece é que, eu não consigo cadastrar nada no model, porque a partial view que eu fiz pra fazer o cadastro não carrega, é por isso que não cadastrei nada. Ou melhor, deixa eu tentar outra forma, @CesarMiguel teria como eu fazer uma partial view pra listar ? E depois renderizar essa outra partial pra cadastrar ?

Comment: Secalhar o Model.Ocorrencias esta a vir sem dados. Mete um breackpoint no controller e ve se vem com dados

Comment: Já fiz isso também.. E ele não para, ele passa direto, é como se não tivesse o breakpoint. Eu não estou entendendo nada. Será que eu tenho que criar uma partial class pra que ele renderize ? Andei pesquisando e vi que tem essa partial class.

Comment: Mete o código do teu controller na questão para dar uma vista de olhos

Comment: Alterações feitas, controller presente !

Comment: Tens dados de alunos nas ocorrências na bd? Não deves ter

Comment: A tabela já tá lá. Mas não cadastrei nada porque não estou conseguindo abrir a partial view... Ou seja, tenho a tabela Alunos, que já tem dados, e a tabela de ocorrências que num tem nada. Mas a tabela aluno já tem a referência para as ocorrências assim como as ocorrências tem a referência para alunos. Mas o caso é que não estou conseguindo renderizar o partial pra cadastrar e não sei porque.

Comment: Então está explicado! Estás a fazer uma consulta onde verificas se há alunos nas ocorrências, como não tens o Model vai a vazio... Ao verificares na view o Model no if, e como não tem nada vai para o else. Vai à base de dados e faz la uma ocorrência à "unha" e já vais ver que dá. Devias seguir uns tutoriais antes de fazer um projecto logo de cabeça...

Comment: Tem algum link que eu possa usar como referência pra que eu faça essa ação ai no banco ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seguindo as boas práticas do MVC, se seu projeto é mínimo, você tem que ser capaz de inserir uma ocorrência mesmo não tendo a tela de Alunos pronta.

Para inserir a ocorrência, modifique seu `Controller` para o seguinte:

### Controllers/OcorrenciasController.cs

```
// http://seusite/Ocorrencias/Adiciona
// Aqui não tem argumentos e não salva nada no banco porque aqui 
// o Controller apenas devolve uma tela parcialmente preenchida.
// Repare que neste caso como não tem Id de Aluno, você vai ter que montar a DropDown.
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult Adiciona()
{
    ViewBag.Alunos = db.Alunos.ToList();
    return View();
}

// http://seusite/Ocorrencias/Adiciona/5
// Aqui tem um argumento só, que é o Id do Aluno.
// Neste caso, o Controller também devolve uma tela parcialmente preenchida, 
// só que neste caso o Aluno já vem preenchido.
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult Adiciona(long id) /* Esse Id é de Aluno, não de Ocorrencia */
{
    var aluno = db.Alunos.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
    var ocorrencia = new Ocorrencia
    {
        Aluno = aluno
    };

    return View(ocorrencia);
}

// É neste caso que você está salvando uma ocorrência de fato por POST.
// Repare que o método aceita um objeto inteiro de ocorrência, e este é o 
// único método que pode salvar alguma coisa, e não o método que você estava fazendo.
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Adiciona(Ocorrencia ocorrencia)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        db.Ocorrencias.Add(ocorrencia);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    // Se o Model não for válido, você tem que montar a ViewBag de novo.
    ViewBag.Alunos = db.Alunos.ToList();

    return View(ocorrencia);
}
```

### Views/Ocorrencias/Create.cshtml

```
@model CEF01.Models.Ocorrencia

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    if (Model.AlunoId != null) 
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AlunoId)
    } else {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AlunoId, ((IEnumerable<Aluno>)ViewBag.Alunos).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
            Text = option.Nome, 
            Value = option.Id.ToString(),
            Selected = (Model != null) && (option.Id == Model.AlunoId)
        }), "Selecione...")
    }

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Ocorrencia</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tipo, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tipo)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tipo)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Causa, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Causa)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Causa)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Observacao, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Observacao)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Observacao)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Assim você pode facilmente inserir ocorrências fora da tela de Aluno para terminar sua tela de Aluno:

`http://seusite/Ocorrencias/Create`
`http://seusite/Ocorrencias/Create/IdDoAluno`

Answer (score 2):

substitua

```
@Html.Partial("_AdicionaOcorrencia", ocorrencia)
```

por

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_AdicionaOcorrencia", ocorrencia);}
```

sempre que for retornar uma partial view, no controle substitua o ActionResult porPartialViewResult.

Com ActionResult funciona, mas por questão de combinação de requisição e retorno utilize o PartialViewResult quando for retornar uma partial view